# Why does baby Kal-El's pod land in a different spot in Flashpoint?

Tags: dc, superman, flashpoint-paradox, flashpoint

In both the *Flashpoint* storyline and *Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox* animated adaptation, we find out at the end that the Flashpoint timeline was created by

> Barry Allen going back in time to save his mom.

I can maybe understand why this would result in a butterfly effect causing changes to other superheroes on Earth (e.g. perhaps a police officer didn't need to come to the Allen house, so their different patrol route impacted the mugging of the Wayne family).

But I can't understand how this change could possibly impact baby Kal-El's pod landing not in Smallville, Kansas, but in downtown Metropolis. How could this have happened, given that the pod was in outer space when the source of the timeline shift happened?

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but the disruption to the timeline occurred before Kal-El’s pod entered the atmosphere, chronologically. Right?

Comment: @Adamant Yes, it did. My question is that I don't see how saving the life of Barry's mother could result in the pod landing somewhere else. What could possibly have been the chain of events between her being saved and the pod, which was in outer space at the time, landing in a different spot.

Comment: It could change the weather patterns. ;) Standard butterfly effect. It’s the classic example.

Comment: @Adamant That would have to be a monumental weather pattern. Weather doesn't cause NASA space ships entering our atmosphere to deviate the distance between Kansas and Metropolis (somewhere on the east coast). And no weather in space of course.

Comment: Well, if you prefer, the light from Earth reached the pod long before it reached Earth. That could have been sufficient to perturb its orbit such that it would land in a different place. (And viz a viz weather, who says it *wasn’t*? His pod could have been hit by a tornado for all we know. It could have been knocked off course by a collision with a flying super-individual. It could have hit some space junk created by whatever space program wouldn’t have existed without Flashpoint. The possibilities are endless.)

Comment: @Adamant I see your point about the butterfly effect potentially creating any number of possibilities. I suppose I'm hoping for an answer that will have the simplest one.

Comment: Maybe the "time boom" distorted space-time around the earth, causing it to have rotated slightly more or less when the vessel arrived? Maybe the "time boom" was detected by the kryptonian vessel, which then decided to avoid the source (although not by very much in astronomical scales). The possibilities are endless and as far as i know, we haven't been given an explanation.

Comment: The "time-boom" effected more than just Earth seeing as Abin Sir was still alive in the comic.

Answer (score 5):

Because of the time boom, as mentioned by Reverse Flash:

> It wouldn't have changed
>   what happened before her murder.
>   Bruce's parents, Clark's landing.
>   Oh, but it did.
>   Break the sound barrier
>   and there's a sonic boom.
>   You broke the time barrier, Flash.
>   Time boom.
>   Ripples of distortion radiated out
>   through that point of impact...
>   ...shifting everything just a tiny bit.
>   But enough.
>   Enough for events to happen
>   slightly differently. -[springfieldspringfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=justice-league-the-flashpoint-paradox)

Also in question, you said you can understand how it changed for Batman but that event also occurred before Flash's mom's death. So Flash's time travel even changed the event occurred the time when he messed with time but some effects befoe it too due to time boom.

Comment: Your quote comes from the movie adaptation. Does this explanation only exist in that, or does it also exist in the original comic book event?

Comment: I didn’t read the comics, so can’t say. Will dig more about comics later

Answer (score 3):

The reason as stated in Flashpoint was a bottled Speed Force. The speed force trickles out gravimetrically causing the rotation to accelerate. No Barry no massive speed force drain

Comment: It would be a good idea to add a canon source.

Comment: Can you provide evidence for your claim?